# Calling a method inside v_bind:class doesn't work (vue js)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Inside the `Posts.vue` component, I execute a couple of methods to retrieve the posts, get post creator info like `Image` and `Username`, as well as checking if the post has been liked.

Everything is working perfectly, except for the last method.

When a post has been liked it adds the class "active", so I created the `isPostLiked()` method and it only returns a true or false (`boolean`).

The template looks like **this**:

```
<button class="btn love button-circle" v-bind:class="{'active': isPostLiked(item)}" v-on:click="likePost(item, index)">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

The method looks like **this**:

```
isPostLiked(post) {
    if (this.auth) {
        axios.get(`/api/getpostlikestatus/${post.id}`)
            .then(res=>{
                return (res.data === 1);
            });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried to get it outside the class with a `v-if` and it still doesn't work, the method works because I've tried to alert its result, and it gives `true`/`false`.

Any ideas of why am I facing this problem? The code doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Your request is async and you are returning in the callback which won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js: v-bind:class after axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770736/vue-js-v-bindclass-after-axios-request)

Comment: set isPostLiked on state and use the value from there. problem is, the if(this.auth) block does not return anything. the return value is just return for the anon function

Comment: Have you try to use $forceUpdate() after your request ?